# How do I get a sequence from a generating function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, polynomials, generating-functions

For example if I have the generating function $\frac{1}{1-2x}$ then it corresponds to the sequence $1 + 2x + 4x^2 + 8x^3 +~...$. I know how to start from the sequence and get the generating function, but I don't know how to start from the generating function and get the sequence.

Similarly, what if I have a generating function like $\frac{1}{1+x}$? How do I get the corresponding sequence? Same way?

Comment: If you know the Taylor series of $\frac{1}{1-x}$ in a neighbourhood of the origin, you also know the Taylor series of $\frac{1}{1+x}$. Just replace $x$ with $-x$ to get $$\frac{1}{1+x}=\sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^n x^n.$$

Comment: In general, if you have a rational function, its partial fraction decomposition gives you the associated sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the following may help you. If you have a linear recurrence of the form
$$
u_{n+2}+a\cdot u_{n+1}+b\cdot u_n=0 \tag1
$$ then, multiplying out $(1)$ by $x^{n+2}$ and summing one gets 
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty u_{n+2}x^{n+2}+a\cdot \sum_{n=0}^\infty u_{n+1}x^{n+2}+b\cdot \sum_{n=0}^\infty u_nx^{n+2}=0\tag2
$$ or, with changes of index,
$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty u_{n}x^n+a\cdot x\sum_{n=1}^\infty u_{n}x^{n}+b\cdot x^2\sum_{n=0}^\infty u_nx^{n}=0\tag3
$$
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty u_{n}x^n+a\cdot x\sum_{n=0}^\infty u_{n}x^{n}+b\cdot x^2\sum_{n=0}^\infty u_nx^{n}=u_0+(u_1+au_0)\cdot x\tag4
$$ that is, by factorizing $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty u_{n}x^n=f(x)$,
$$
(1+ax+b x^2)f(x)=u_0+(u_1+au_0)\cdot x
$$ and

> $$
> f(x)=\frac{u_0+(u_1+au_0)\cdot x}{1+ax+b x^2} \tag5
> $$

Going from $(1)$ to $(5)$ and vice-versa is a usual link between a generating function and a recurrent relation between its coefficients.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42476/discussion-on-answer-by-olivier-oloa-how-do-i-get-a-sequence-from-a-generating-f). It looked like your exchange was completed and could be deleted. If you need to revisit some of the comments, they can be found from that chatroom.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen Thank you.