# Deriving the sequence if the generating function is irreducible?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, generating-functions, partial-fractions

I am trying to better understand generating functions and how they can be derived / manipulated / etc.

Right now I am operating on this identity, slightly modified from the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1858508/51819):

For a recurrence $u_n$ such that $u_{n+2}+au_{n+1} + bu_n = h(n)$, we have:

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}u_n x^n = \frac{u_0 + x \cdot(u_1 + au_0) + x^2 \cdot \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} h(n) x^n}{1 + ax + bx^2}$$

So for any generating function, you can decompose it into partial fractions and each piece can be solved by the above identity... but is this always true?

What about a generating function that has an irreducible denominator after applying partial fractions that does not fit the above?

For example

$$f(n) = \frac{1}{x^3-x-1}$$

which cannot be broken down further with partial fractions and also does not fit the above structure.

Comment: Sure it can. You need to work over the complex numbers, though.

Comment: How would I properly split up the example function I gave so that it can be modified by the identity? I'm not familiar with partial fractions over complex numbers. Wolfram Alpha also shows no solution, http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=partial+fractions+1%2F(x%5E3-x-1)

Comment: Every polynomial of degree more than 2 is a factor of polynomials of degrees 1 and 2. For example, $1+x-x^3=(1-ax)(1-ux)(1-\bar ux)$ for some suitable real $a$ and complex number $u$ and $$\frac1{1+x-x^3}=\frac{c}{1-ax}+\frac{v}{1-ux}+\frac{w}{1-\bar ux}$$ for some suitable $(c,v,w)$ hence $$\frac1{1+x-x^3}=\sum_{n\geqslant0}(ca^n+vu^n+w\bar u^n)x^n.$$